# The output parameter 'CopiedFiles' of Copy task is returning all the files specified to copy even if it copies nothing given SkipUnchangedFiles="true"

Tags: msbuild, copy, task

The CopiedFiles parameter is returning all the files that were intended to be copied. But given the fact that SkipUnchangedFiles is set to true and ttask itself is not copying anything as can be seen on command line (no copying message). Why not, then, CopiedFiles is empty?

I need to have CopiedFiles parameter be populated only with files that were actually copied (because they were changed) in order to further copy these files into some other folder. This is to maintain an up-to-date release folder as well as to extract only those files which actually need to be propogated onto UAT/production server.

For reference sake, the copy task code I'm using is given below:

```
<Copy SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
            SourceFiles="@(cfile)"
                DestinationFiles="@(cfile->'$(PublishDir)\%(Identity)')">

        <Output
                    TaskParameter="CopiedFiles"
                    ItemName="Changed" />

</Copy>

<Message Text="changed:@(Changed)" Importance="high" />
```

Is there a bug in the copy task or this is the intended behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is by design.  MSBuild keeps track of file dependencies using task outputs.  If it were to do otherwise, anything that relied on the @(Changed) item array as an input would not fully process all of the files it needed in most cases.  It will even keep track of properties and items created within targets that don't even execute when Inputs and Outputs are up-to-date, for the same reason.  Consider making a different Copy task of your own with an additional output parameter, CopiedFilesCopiedByTask (this naming mirrors the naming and behavior of the ValueSetByTask in the otherwise defunct CreateProperty task).

Comment: If this is by design, then why is MSDN contradicting it. [Copy task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) It says "CopiedFiles: Contains the items that were successfully copied."

Comment: You're right, it's worth a footnote, it should say "...or that would have been copied if they weren't up-to-date, and were skipped because SkipUnchangedFiles was set to true."  The task will behave deterministically with respect to dependency analaysis regardless of the value of SkipUnchangedFiles.

Comment: The docs has been updated:

"Contains the items that were successfully copied, including those that were not actually copied, but were skipped because they were already up-to-date and SkipUnchangedFiles was true."

Without rewriting the Copy task to also return three extra file lists (actually copied, skipped unchanged, and failed because of errors), I use a simple date check to split the source list into 'new' and 'unchanged' files (based on your code, untested):

Comment: <_newFiles Include="@(cfile)"
                  Condition=" $([System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime('$(PublishDir)\%(Identity)').get_Ticks()) &lt; $([System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime('%(Identity)').get_Ticks()) " />

(sorry, can't get code formatting to work here)

That should be done before the Copy task, of course.